# Perché si chiama "congiuntivo"?

Tags: etymology

Un aspetto della lingua italiana che mi ha sempre incuriosita è l'uso del termine "congiuntivo" per riferirsi al modo verbale che in inglese è chiamato "subjunctive", in castigliano "subjuntivo", in catalano "subjuntiu", in francese "subjonctif", ecc.

Cercando il termine ["congiuntivo" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/congiuntivo), però, ho visto che anche in italiano si era adoperato "soggiuntivo" nel passato.

Avevo sempre pensato che le forme imparentate con l'inglese "subjunctive" avessero qualcosa a che fare con "soggettività". Tuttavia, guardando l'etimologia di ["soggiuntivo"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000297.jpg) vedo che hanno piuttosto a che vedere con "soggiungere", dunque credo che mi fossi sbagliata.

Ricercando anche informazioni sull'etimologia di  ["congiuntivo"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000559.jpg), vedo che è un termine etimologicamente imparentato col verbo "congiungere". Un'accezione di ["soggiungere"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soggiungere), oggi disusata, è precisamente "congiungere": quindi adesso vedo una correlazione tra l'etimologia di questi due vocaboli, "soggiuntivo" e "congiuntivo".

Tuttavia, vi chiedo: cosa ha a che fare il modo congiuntivo dei verbi con l'idea di "congiungere"?

Comment: A me alle elementari avevano insegnato che era perché era il modo introdotto dalle congiunzioni... non che abbia molto senso per cui lo lascio solo come commento.

Comment: @DenisNardin:  Infatti ["congiunzione"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/congiunzione) 
 è anche etimologicamente correlato con "congiungere".

Comment: @DenisNardin: Tuttavia, è vero che è un modo tipico di molte subordinate introdotte da congiunzioni.

Comment: @DenisNardin No, di senso non ne ha proprio. Congiunzioni come "ma" ed "e" non hanno nulla a che fare con il congiuntivo.

Comment: @Charo Le subordinate sono necessariamente e non "tipicamente" introdotte da congiunzioni. Un fondamento di grammatica ci vorrebbe.

Comment: "Ricercando anche informazione sull'etimologia di "congiuntivo", vedo che è un termine etimologicamente imparentato col verbo "congiungere". Un'accezione di "soggiungere", oggi disusata, è precisamente "congiungere": quindi adesso vedo una correlazione tra l'etimologia di questi due vocaboli, "soggiuntivo" e "congiuntivo".
Tuttavia, vi chiedo: cosa ha a che fare il modo congiuntivo dei verbi con l'idea di "congiungere"? Avevi chiesto di corregerti e lo faccio volentieri. "Tuttavia" non si usa in italiano  come sinonimo di "comunque sia", ma solo per indicare contrasto.

Comment: È 'conjuntivo' in portoghese.

Comment: @DenisNardin: A me non sembra un'idea tanto assurda. Dal [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000559.jpg): «si usa per lo più in proposizioni subordinate». In certo senso, la congiunzione subordinata "congiunge" col verbo (frequentemente) al congiuntivo. Mi sembra proprio un'idea per tentare di ricercare se si trova qualcosa.

Comment: Grazie, @entonio: ho eliminato il portoghese del testo della domanda (veramante del portoghese non ne ero sicura, delle altre lingue sì).

Comment: Seguendo l'indizio fornito da @DenisNardin, sono riuscita a trovare questo: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/uso-del-congiuntivo/104.

Comment: Anche nell'*Italiano* di Serianni si trova: "è il modo tipico delle proposizioni dipendenti (si chiama così proprio perché «congiunge» alla principale subordinate di vario tipo, [...]), [...]". L'ho visto solo ora perché questa informazione appare soltanto nel glossario alla fine del libro.

Answer (score 3):

Trovo questo passo in uno scritto di Maurus Servius Honoratus:

> Dum regna manebant 'dum' donec: et absolutus est sensus. alii tamen 'cum' legunt: sed 'cum manebant' quomodo dicimus, cum constet 'manebant' modum esse indicativum? hoc ergo sciendum est, quia, quando coniunctivus modus est, necesse est aliquid iungi aut subaudiri, ut 'cum venirem, vidi illum'. si autem 'cum veniebam' dicamus, aut modus pro modo est, hoc est indicativus pro coniunctivo: aut 'cum' non erit coniunctio, sed adverbium temporis, et significat 'tempore quo veniebam'.

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0053:book=2:commline=455&highlight=coniunctivus

Trovo anche http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=conjunctivus&la=la#lexicon

> conjunctīvus , a, um, adj. id.,
>   I.of connection or serving to connect, connective (in post-class. gram. lang.): “particula (sc. autem),” Tert. adv. Hermog. 26.—Esp. freq.: conjunctivus modus, or absol.: conjunc-tīvus , i, m., the conjunctive or subjunctive mood, Mart. Cap. 3, § 310 al.

Ma trovo anche http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=subjunctivus&la=la#lexicon

> subjunctīvus , a, um, adj. subjungo,
>   I.of or belonging to binding together, connecting; in the later gram. lang., modus, the subjunctive mood, Diom. p. 331 P.; Prisc. p. 820 ib. al.: “conjunctiones, e. g. si, cum, antequam, etc.,” Charis. p. 200 sq. P.: “vocales,” Prisc. 561 ib.

Sembra proprio che i grammatici latini abbiano adoperato sia *coniunctivus* sia *subiunctivus* (sostituisco la *j* che proprio non mi piace) per nominare il modo verbale corrispondente.

Comment: Grazie, @egreg: si accennava a qualcosa su questo nella domanda.

Comment: Scusa, @egreg: non è "Maurus Servius Honoratus"? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurus_Servius_Honoratus). Accade anche che i link che hai messo a me non funzionino del tutto bene.

Comment: @Charo Ho corretto il nome (errore di copiatura). I link a me funzionano.

Comment: Interessante il passo «hoc est indicativus pro coniunctivo: aut 'cum' non erit coniunctio, sed adverbium temporis, et significat 'tempore quo veniebam'», che sembra essere correlato all'idea di @DenisNardin e a quello che spiega l'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo quanto spiega questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/uso-del-congiuntivo/104), il termine *subiuntivus* era usato nella tradizione grammaticale latina per indicare il modo verbale usato in qualsiasi proposizione subordinata. A quanto pare della prima citazione nella risposta di @egreg, anche *coniunctivus* era usato con lo stesso significato:

> Nella tradizione grammaticale latina il termine SUBIUNCTIVUS ('congiuntivo') era usato per indicare il modo verbale usato nelle subordinate in genere, per questo dalle prime grammatiche italiane (Fortunio del 1516 o Giambullari del 1552 ad esempio) fino all'Ottocento i termini *subienctivo*, *soggiuntivo* si impiegarono per ogni forma verbale usata in una frase dipendente da una principale. Soltanto alla fine del XIX secolo, con le grammatiche di Fornaciari, Zambaldi e Morandi-Cappuccini, si cominciò a privilegiare nella definizione del congiuntivo il valore semantico più di quello sintattico ed anche le grammatiche attuali più tradizionali definiscono il congiuntivo come uno dei modi finiti del verbo (con indicativo, condizionale, imperativo) che serve a presentare l'azione espressa dal verbo come incerta, ipotizzabile, desiderata, dubbia o soggettiva.

Anche nel glossario alla fine dell'*Italiano* di Serianni si trova:

> è il modo tipico delle proposizioni dipendenti (si chiama così proprio perché «congiunge» alla principale subordinate di vario tipo, [...]), [...].

Dunque, a quanto pare, ambedue i termini, "soggiuntivo" e "congiuntivo", deriverebbero dell'idea di modo verbale caratteristico delle proposizioni subordinate.