# "Mi ha incuriosito/a" versus "mi sono incuriosito/a"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, agreement, auxiliary-verb

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11618/), l'ausiliare del verbo "incuriosire" mi è stato corretto da "essere" ad "avere". Capisco la correzione senza problema: è semplicemente che a volte diventa difficile per me ricordare che "incuriosire" è transitivo, mentre invece "piacere" è intransitivo.

Cercando ["incuriosire" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incuriosire), però, ho visto che questo verbo ha anche un uso intransitivo.

Allora, per assicurarmi di aver capito bene, potrei dire queste frasi?

- Questo fatto mi ha sempre incuriosita (uso transitivo di "incuriosire").
- Mi sono sempre incuriosita di questo fatto (uso intransitivo di "incuriosire").

Ho scritto "incuriosita" perché ho pensato a me pronunciando queste frasi. [Capisco](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9908/), però, che nella prima frase potrei dire "mi ha incuriosito" e forse è più frequente nell'italiano moderno.

È veramente così?

Comment: Faccio fatica a pensare a qualsiasi frase riflessiva con "avere".

Comment: La concordanza del participio si fa se il nome o pronome lo precede: “ti avevo lasciato due libri, li hai letti?” Nella tua frase può anche andare “incuriosito”, comunque.

Comment: Quanto alla domanda specifica, la seconda alternativa mi suona molto male.

Comment: @egreg: Tuttavia, secondo il Treccani, si può dire *s’era incuriosito di sapere perché mai avessi rimandato la mia partenza* o *s’incuriosiva di quei costumi*.

Comment: @Charo Infatti, mi suona male, ma non escludo si possa usare. *Incuriosirsi* non è riflessivo se non nella forma. È più una “forma media”.

Comment: Riguardo alla concordanza, è quello che si spiega  [qui](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/accordo-del-participio-passato/23).

Comment: Mi sembrava che ci fosse già qualche domanda sugli [intransitivi pronominali](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-pronominali_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), ma non ne trovo.

Comment: @DaG: E io che pensavo che questa fosse una domanda di risposta facile. L'unico che sono riuscita a capire è che gli intransitivi pronominali si coniugano come i riflessivi (dall'*Italiano* di Serianni).

Comment: Sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/incuriosirsi), il verbo intransitivo pronominale "incuriosirsi" (attenzione, non il verbo transitivo ["incuriosire"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/incuriosire)) viene marcato come ["CO"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6) e forse questo spiega l'osservazione fatta da @egreg. Cioè, a quanto pare, è di uso meno comune di "incuriosire" transitivo.

Comment: E, per complicare ancora di più le cose (dal mio personale punto di vista), esiste anche un "incuriosire" intransitivo non pronominale di cui il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Libera?q=incuriosire) fa questo esempio di Emilio Cecchi: «La  gente  che  a  frotte  tornava  agli uffici,  dopo  il  desinare  e  la  siesta,  incuriosiva  ritrovandolo sul proprio cammino».